# Wordpress Post by Category

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a website with Wordpress. What i need is make a page which shows only post with a specific category. What shall I do?

For instance, page Javascript, only displays post with the cateogry Javascript.

Comment: This should be built into Wordpress. Using your example of viewing posts in the javascript category: `http://yourwebsite.com/category/javascript/`. This assumes you have permalinks on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how good you are with PHP, but you need to create a Wordpress template where it queries the posts from your category.

You can read about the archive page here where it displays all your posts:

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-wordpress-archives-template-for-your-theme/

Just before this:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Add this to query it to a specific category:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=News'); ?>
```

Where 'News' is your category name!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php query_posts('cat=1'); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title();?>

   <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

You can read more about query_post here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts
```